# What structure is required for my neighbors adjoining fence?

Tags: fence

My next door neighbor has a drive way and the council workers have put a gate up (looks like 6ft fence panels). The post that is next to my fence has simply been drilled through my fence and into a post I have. The post is not sunk or anything just drilled into my fence with three screws.

Will what they have done weaken my exiting post? Is what they have done suitable for a 6ft gate?

Comment: Was this a story, a rant, or did you have a specific question?

Comment: Sorry about that just so annoyed, Will what they have done weaken my exiting post? is what they have done suitable for a 6ft gate?

Comment: The rant and possible legal questions are off topic here, so I've edited the question down to the parts that are on topic. See our [faq] if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: Posts usually support fences. Your description sounds like the fence is supporting the post, in which case the gate would likely fail immediately. What IS supporting the post?

Comment: Picture is worth a thousand words...

Answer (score 2):

Fences usually have posts of 2 sizes or grades.

Line post are smaller diameter and not as well braced, as they support only fence.

End posts are larger and better braced for extras like gates.
They are meant for tensioning  chain link fences.

If they've attached to a line post, it will probably not support a gate for long.

I would insist that they support the gate with a properly braced post ( usually involving concrete).

Comment: I second the notion of requesting the post to be properly set.  I find it amazing that they did this to be quite honest.